# Problem with compiling scss in webpack - webpack mixes old code with the new one

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

I cannot resolve problem with compiling scss...

I've started tu build a website in gulp and then I've changed everything to webpack. The problem is that right now old code is mixed with the new one... Example:

In code I have this:

```
&__logo {
  &-icon {
    width: 150px;
    img {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```

but in console I can see this (main.scss):

```
header .header__logo-icon {
    width: 150px;
}
```

AND THIS:

```
header .header__logo-icon (_header.scss) {
    padding: 1rem;
    color: white;
}
```

Padding and color is from the old code. In main.css I have only version with padding and color.

My webpack config looks like this:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './js/script.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/build',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  watch: true,
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: { presets: ['es2015'] }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|csv)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            publicPath: 'img',
            outputPath: 'img'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

And in script.js I have this:

```
require('../scss/main.scss');
```

Does anyone has idea how to fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should connect css + scss

```js
{
  test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader'
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        importLoaders: 2,
        sourceMap: true,
      },
    },
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

I recommend getting acquainted with some webpack-boilerplate on github